# Polymer 2.0 app-router subroutes not working

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am new to polymer and a little confused on how to perform subroutes effectively in the PWA app. I have a structure in mind and wish to understand how it can be done. I tried using youtube tutorial but it didn't work.

app structure -

```
my-app
 + landing-page (/landing)
 + dashboard-page (/dashboard)
 + transaction-page (/transactions) 
     + list-page (/transastions/list)
     + detail-page (/transastions/detail/:id)
```

I created app-routes in my-app.html

```
 <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="[[rootPath]]:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}">
 </app-route>

<iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="not-found-404"
        role="main">
      <landing-page name="landing-page"></landing-page>
      <dashboard-page name="dashboard-page"></dashboard-page>
      <anynew-page name="anynew-page"></anynew-page>
      <not-found name="not-found-404"></not-found>
      <transactions-page name="transactions-page" route="{{subroute}}"></transactions-page>
```

in transactions-page

```
<dom-module id="transactions-page">
```

```
    <style include="shared-styles">
  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
</style>

<app-data key="userData" data="{{storedUser}}"></app-data>

<app-route  route="{{route}}"
              pattern="/tranlist"
            data="{{storeData}}"
                tail="{{subRoute}}"
            active="{{listActive}}"></app-route>

<app-route  route="{{subRoute}}"
                pattern="/trandetail/:Id"
            data="{{indvidualStoreData}}"
            active="{{detailActive}}"></app-route>

<list-page    viewtype="{{view.type}}"
              activestate={{listActive}}></list-page>

<detail-page  viewtype="{{view.type}}"
              individualdataId={{indvidualStoreData.Id}}
              activestate="{{detailActive}}"></detail-page>

<div class="card">
  <div class="circle">SP</div>
  <h1>This is a Transactions Page</h1>
</div> 

 <iron-selector selected="{{view.type}}" attr-for-selected="data-page">
    <a data-page="list" href="{{route}}/transaction/list">List</a>
    <a data-page="detail" href="{{subRoute}}/:id">Detail</a>
 </iron-selector>
```

list-page.html and detail-page.html is polymer elements with simple iron-ajax call and nothing but a copy of youtube polycast #46 - carbon routing.

list-page.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<dom-module id="list-page">
<template>
<style>
  :host {
    display: none;
  }
  :host([active]) {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="[[_computeURL(viewtype)]]"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{listData}}"></iron-ajax>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{listData.posts}}">
  <div class="post">
    <a href="#/[[viewtype]]/storeid/[[item.id]]">
      <img src="[[item.img]]" alt="[[item.img_alt]]" />
      <h2>[[item.title]]</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
 </template>
 <script>

class ListPage extends Polymer.Element {
static get is() { return 'list-page'; }
static get properties() {
  return {
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      reflectToAttribute: true
    };
  }
}
   _computeURL(viewtype) {
   return `data/list/${viewtype}.json`;
// API construct list url http://localhost:3000/transaction
  }

  window.customElements.define(ListPage.is, ListPage);
 }
 </script>
 </dom-module>
```

detail-page.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<dom-module id="detail-page">
 <template>
  <style>
  :host {
    display: none;
  }
  :host([active]) {
    display: block;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 33.18px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
  </style>
  <iron-ajax
    auto
    url="[[_computeURL(individualdataId)]]"
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{postContent}}"></iron-ajax>
    <h2>[[postContent.title]]</h2>
     <p>[[postContent.intro_text]]</p>
  <img src="[[postContent.img]]" alt="[[postContent.img_alt]]" />
  <p>[[postContent.body_text]]</p>
 </template>
 <script>

  class DetailPage extends Polymer.Element {
static get is() { return 'detail-page'; }
static get properties() {
  return {
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      reflectToAttribute: true
    };
  }
}
   _computeURL(individualdataId) {
   return `data/detail/${individualdataId}.json`;
// API construct list url http://localhost:3000/transaction/id
  }

  window.customElements.define(DetailPage.is, DetailPage);
  }
```

Comment: I plan to replace the ajax dummy data with api calls

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response... the error in Chrome browser when I console out the status of the URL is -        transactions-page
my-app.html:302 url is ->http://127.0.0.1:8081/src/transactions-page.html
my-app.html:301 [object Object]
my-app.html:302 url is ->http://127.0.0.1:8081/src/[object%20Object].html
my-app.html:301 not-found-404
my-app.html:302 url is ->http://127.0.0.1:8081/src/not-found-404.html. I think the issue is in transaction-page the way the URLs are getting href. What I wish is show transactions and then on click show details of the transaction

Comment: Have you defined `app-location` in `my-app.html` above `app-route`?\

Comment: yes in my-app.html just above <app-route> I have app-location declared. <app-location route="{{route}}" url-space-regex="^[[rootPath]]"></app-location>

Comment: The problem might be you are using `{{route}}` and `{{subroute}}` in `iron-selector` in transaction-page. Change that to route.path and subroute.path. The problem is there.